# two sums problem- how to overcome specific error?

Tags: python, loops

so I have a list of integers, num, and a target integer. Nums is such that two of the numbers will add up to the target. I have written the code below to return the indices of these two numbers, but I am getting a 'int object is not iterable' error.

I understand what this error is, but I do not know how to amend the code to fix it- any suggestions? Thanks!

```
 def TwoSum(self, nums, target):
     for i, a in enumerate(nums, start= 0):
         for j,b in enumerate(nums[i+1], start = 0):
             if a+b== target:
                 return [i,j+i+1]
```

Comment: I think you stuck at this problem. [https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are splitting your `list` wrong!

`list_of_ints[i]` gives an integer (and you can NOT iterate on an integer)

`list_of_ints[i:]` gives a list from ith index till end

```
def TwoSum(self, nums, target):
     for i, a in enumerate(nums, start= 0):
         for j,b in enumerate(nums[i+1:], start = 0): #nums[i+1] is a single integer
             if a+b== target:
                 return [i,j+i+1]
```